# Can the Apache2 www-data user spawned by Apache's root process have restricted access to files through group permissions?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, user-permissions

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, LAMP stack installed with `apt-get`, everything works fine.

Sometimes, however, I am experiencing the following error when my PHP program (PHP runs with `Server API Apache 2.0 Handler`) tries to write a file inside of a directory owned by a group different by the `www-data` main group (which is `www-data`), but to whom `www-data` belongs too (I added the `www-data` user to this other group and made it its secondary group).

Therefore: PHP runs with Apache as `www-data:www-data` (user:group), the `www-data` user in turn belongs to another group too (it's called `smsd`, it is the group of a SMS daemon I use), and when PHP needs to write to a folder like this:

```
drwxrwsr-t  2 smsd smsd 4096 Jul 10 11:40 outgoing/
```

Which is owned by `smsd:smsd` (note that the group can write inside `outgoing`), sometimes PHP can write to this folder, sometimes it can't!

Is there a reasonable explanation of this behaviour? The Apache version is 2.4, PHP version is 7.

`id www-data`:

```
me@machine:/var/spool/sms# id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),131(smsd)
```

See how it outputs that `www-data` belongs to `smsd` too.

The strange thing also is as I said, that this doesn't happen systematically. Sometimes `www-data` can write to this folder and it successfully creates a file (`return array('status' => 'ok');`), sometimes it can't and my script doesn't write the file (`return array('err' => 'Error writing file.');`):

```
//...
$smsdSMSFileText = <<<EOF
To: $to
Alphabet: UTF-8

$message
EOF;
        if (!file_put_contents($smsdSMSFileName, $smsdSMSFileText)) {
            return array('err' => 'Error writing file.');
        }
        return array('status' => 'ok');
//...
```

Maybe it's because some of the spawned children of Apache run without the secondary groups (only as `www-data:www-data`)? Is it possible?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Anything in the various error logs at the time the file cannot be created?

Comment: It is funny, maybe you won't believe me, but now it seems to work and I always get `array('status' => 'ok')`. I changed permissions to `drwxrwsrwt  2 smsd smsd 4096 Jul 10 11:40 outgoing/` (because I didn't know why I was experiencing the error) and now I changed them again to `drwxrwsr-t  2 smsd smsd 4096 Jul 10 11:40 outgoing/` (removed `others` write permission) and tried many times to request the page which creates the file, everything seems fine. Anyway, I tried `zcat /var/log/apache2/error.log.*.gz  | grep PHP` but it seems that those log are pretty old as I don't get any output.

Comment: @Nitin I will leave the permissions to `drwxrwsr-t 2 smsd smsd 4096 Jul 10 11:40 outgoing/` and let you know if the error happens again, so I can post the error_log. Anyway, do you think it's possible that the apache thread behaves in such an abnormal way?

Comment: I can think of two cases: caching or server misconfig. If you updated the shadow file, then try running sudo fuser -k kill any open processes and clearing the cache. But honestly, it could be anything. Sudo apt-get update and apt-get upgrade maybe?

Comment: If you experience it again, here to help